# Plot a system of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, system

I would like to plot the solutions to the system of ODEs that is written below:

```
smax = -0.668;
t = Flatten@Table[0.2 + i, {i, 0, 1, 1.5}]
Sol = NDSolveValue[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == dΔ0[s]*Dsonic[s], 
 R'[s] == Dsonic[s],  F[0] == #, Δ0[0] == Δinit, 
 R[0] == Rinit}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, smax}] & /@ t

Plot[Evaluate@Through[Sol[s]], {s, 0, smax}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[{#[s]}, {s, 0, smax}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ Sol
```

The  `NDSolve` works but iIcan't plot it with what I have written.
I would like to plot F[s] over R[s].
I haven't included the odes in the code because are a bit lengthy.
I can include a script if it is necessary.

Comment: Your `Sol` — avoid starting with capitals, by the way — is a list of a list.  You need to access its parts properly. For instance `Plot[Through[#[s]], {s, 0, smax}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ Sol`. Not sure what you really want. Sounds to me like this: `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{#[[3]][s], #[[1]][s]} & /@ Sol], {s, 0, smax}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: This works fine. Thank you for your help and comments. What if i also wanted to plot another function G[s]  which i have defined  before i do the NDSolve that is a function of F[s],Δ[s],R[s]. Is it possible?

Comment: I guess you can try something like `Show[plot1,plot2]` with `plot1` being what @MichaelE2 suggested and `plot2=Plot[G[s],{s,0,max},PlotRange->All]`